question about net gamma, zero gamma's effect
I have a question about the net gamma like below.
https://support.spotgamma.com/hc/en-us/articles/15413527450899-Net-Gamma
Net gamma is the sum of call gamma minus the sum of put gamma.
1.
"Isn't positive net gamma simply a situation where there are more calls than puts? If so, why does it lead to lower realized volatility (RV)? The explanation states: 'A positive gamma position infers lower realized volatility (RV) in the underlying security, while a negative gamma position implies higher RV.' Can someone explain the mechanics behind this?"
2.
"Even when net gamma is negative due to a large number of puts, market makers (MMs) still engage in hedging activities, right? Isn't this situation essentially the same as positive net gamma in terms of price stabilization effects? How does this align with the statement about negative gamma positions implying higher realized volatility?"

I know, but the spotgamma defined net gamma as |call| - |put| gamma. You can see it in the url. I just dont understand about the RV.

There is nothing about valuation that affects RV. It's like saying you calculating the mass of the sun affects the sun.

Arshdeeep: In the Black Scholes framework RV is indeed exogenous and unchanging. But people who subscribe to these "dealer gamma theories" that are quite popular in the markets now (though I am somewhat skeptical) believe that the hedging behavior of option dealers changes the way the market works so that RV is somewhat endogenous.

@nbbo2 I mean, I understand that ultimately it is demand and supply but it is still not endogenous to an option pricing model (though a trader can mark the model based on his understanding of what you said). I would in this case build a separate model for predicting RV, which again can serve as input to the option pricing model.
